# Retrieve Foreign Key Object Field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

I am writing a view in Django which should be able to retrive my friends locations. It seems pretty straightforward after retrieving my friends list with a basic query; however what I also want to know is the username of the User object, which is a foreign key of my Location model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True)
    altitude = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, default='0', null=True)
    last_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I am querying the model in this way:

> friends_location = Location.objects.filter(user=friends)

This is one of the "Location" objects I get from this query:

> {"fields": {"status": 1, "last_updated_at": "2014-12-10T16:30:29.603Z", "altitude": 0.0, "longitude": -2.21698, "user": 2, "provider": "0", "latitude": 53.456542}, "model": "app.location", "pk": 5}

In this case, instead of getting the Username, I get the id of the object "user:2", so my question is how should I query the model to return the same list but with something like "User.username: edoardo".

Comment: That's not what you get from the query: that's the output of some kind of serialization operation on the result of that query. You should show exactly what you do to get that.

Comment: True, if I return friends location as an http response, I simply get "Location objectLocation objectLocation object", which makes sense, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to select the fields you want. In this case you will have to specify all the fields you want to keep from the results of your queryset.

In order to get the username you would:

```
 # TODO: put all the fieldnames you want to keep inside the values() call
 friends_location = Location.objects.filter(user=friends).values('user__username')
```

--- EDIT ---

As an answer to your comment and the solution suggested by @Alex I think you should read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/) from Django.

Comment: I am getting something like "'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'", which I am not sure what it means..

Comment: You should call it on your queryset, before any kind of serialization. You are getting this error because you are probably calling *values()* on your serialized object.

Comment: I have just copied your query and then serialized friends_location. Alex seemed to have a good hint, but even there I am still getting the user object id.

Comment: The doc pointed in the edit of my answer may provide you some clues on how to get the username when serializing your queryset.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks now it works. It's returning 'user__username': u'edoardo'. The only weird thing is that u at the beginning, do you know what that is? Thanks.

Comment: That *u* is because it is [an unicode (string) literal](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).

Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The location object contains user object, so you can get username like this:

```
for location in Location.objects.filter(user=friends).select_related('user'):
    print(location.user.username)
```

Note. I use `select_related` to avoid additional query to db.

**Update**
For Serialization:

```
>>> serializers.serialize('json', Location.objects.filter(user=friends), indent=4,
...      use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

Comment: Ok, but in this way you are just selecting the username? It would be good to get the whole json object with just the user field changed to username, so I can associate the location to the username.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried to serialize in that way, but I am still getting "user":2. Do I have to include the first query you posted in the serialize in some way in order to get user:edoardo? Thanks.